# Starting TortoiseMerge with Console

Tags: svn, tortoisemerge

I want to see what changes were made in a resvision compared to the previous one.
At the moment I am doing it by opening my local Repo and selecting show log. There I click the option "Compare with previous revision" and it starts TortoiseMerge with the correct files.

For example: I open the text-file Text1.txt
The filenames shown in the Merge-Tool are Text1.txt Revision x-1 and Text1.txt Revison x.

But I want to start it though a batch-script, where you can just enter the Revision and it will show the differneces in TortoiseMerge.

At the moment I use the command

TortoiseMerge [Revision1-path] [Revision2-path]

but I have troubles finding the right revision-paths.
So my question is, where I can find the right files, that I get the same result in TortoiseMerge as if I would open it through the conext-menu.

Comment: Why go through opening the repository, "Show log" and then "Compare"? Right-click the file in Explorer, choose `Tortoise SVN->Diff with previous version` from the context menu.

Comment: I think the way you described, you  only can compare the newest version of the text to the previous version. But i want to be able to compare any revision to the previous one - not only the latest.

Comment: I also need a way to do that with TortoiseMerge... In Linux you can do it with a simple script executing "svn diff | kompare -o -"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post the command I use, just in case someone else is searching for that.
I got that command by using the instruction given by mellow.

```
"[Path]\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:showcompare /nodekind:2 /url1:"[Repo-URL]" /revision1:9 /url2:"[Repo-URL]" /revision2:7 /headpegrevision:HEAD
```

With this command you won't start TortoiseMerge directly, but it will show you what files were changed. Then you can select a file and it will show the changes in TortoiseMerge.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to find the right command line call.

- Just open TortoiseMerge via "Compare with previous revision" as you did before.
- Than drag the Process Explorers 'crosshair' (Find Window's Process) from the toolbar over the TortoiseMerge window.
- Process Explorer jumps to the process.
- Double click that process to view it's properties.
- In the Image tab you can see the field 'Command line' which holds the command line call you can use.

The description of the command line switches used is available in the [TortoiseMerge documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseMerge_en/tme-automation.html#tme-automation-basics).